# GAE fetch() distinct values ordered by time

Tags: database, google-app-engine, gql

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    ts = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    id_from_other_source = db.StringProperty(default='')
    #some data
```

Now I have a list of some ids which match id_from_other_source field.
Data about id changes in time, so for one id there is a lot of data.

I'd like to run such a query that fetches me for each id only one entry of that id that is the youngest.
Something like:

```
MyModel.all().filter('id_from_other_source IN', my_id_list).order('-ts').fetch(1000)
```

But with disctinction in id_from_other_source. I understand that you can't run GQL queries with DISTINCT, but maybe you can see any solution that won't run too much queries?

One solution is to take them one by one and fetch the result, but I'd really like to do it with lesser number of queries.

Comment: The tricky way how I actually did it was to add field recent = True/False to model and update that field in cron once in a while. Then getting objects without limitations. Object was valid for about a week and cron went everyday taking down older tasks. When I then fetched my recent data I had no more than two instances of every id - easy to filter.